# Регулярное выражение - замена скобок

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день.
*Как сделать правильное регулярное выражение?*

Имеется текст:

```
[li]text1[li]text2[/li][/li]
```

С помощью этой регулярки:

```
\[li\](.*?)\[\/li\]
```

Он разбивается так:

```
<li>text1[li]text2</li>[/li]
```

А нужно:

```
<li>text1<li>text2</li></li>
```

Comment: Пробовали так? 

    \[li\](.*)\[\/li\]

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает.

Comment: а если так

    \[li\]([^\[]*)\[\/li\]


и применить два раза.

Comment: Не факт что внутри li будет еще только один li. Их может быть сколько угодно :)

Comment: ну и что? главное, что бы они были правильно вложены.

Хотя думаю, тут не регулярка нужна, а всего две замены:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно так сделать:

```
$string='[li]text1[li]text2[/li][/li]';
$pattern=':\[(/?li[^\]]*)\]:';
echo preg_replace($pattern,"<$1>",$string);
```

или вообще так:

```
$pattern=':\[([^\]]+)\]:';
```

http://ideone.com/wj00gf

полное решение с проверкой тэгов и пр типа такого:

```
$pattern=':(?P<block>\[((?P<tag>[^\s\]]+)[^\]]*)\]((?&block)|[^\]]+)\[/((?P=tag))\]):';
do{
   $string=preg_replace($pattern,'<$2>$4</$5>',$string,-1,$count);
  }
   while($count>0);
```

http://ideone.com/Qu2fmB

должен кстати заметить, что по стандарту HTML тэг `<li>` должен быть включен только в  элементы `<ul>`, `<ol>` или `<menu>`, т.е. код

```
<li> test
   <li> test1 </li>
</li>
```

не верный

---

[image: Regular expression visualization]